# GVIM - Crash during startup

Tags: unix, vim

Recently I wanted to try the gvim7.2 for its wonderful support of CSCOPE and installed it from my company's installation directory. However, when I execute it - I get a segmentation fault and the message looks thus,

```
Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
Vim: Finished.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I was searching for this issue in the online forums, I found general complaints about the reproducibility of the issue. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should try the latest stable version, Vim 7.3.

Comment: I get exactly the same behavior on some version of vim-7.2 found on my ubuntu arm netbook by one of my plugins due to its extensible use of “scope dictionary” feature. It does not happen with recent (not more then a several months old) vim-7.3. So you basically have two options: 1. (prefered) update to vim-7.3. 2. run vim without plugins. If it does run correctly, do `vim -D` (enter debugging mode), press `s<CR>` and continue pressing `<CR>` until you find out what plugin is the issue, then purge it. If it does not bug your admin for keeping broken software, I can’t help you any further.

Answer (score 3):

I have had crashes with incompatible shared libraries for Python3 IIRC.

I never got ultisnips working on Ubuntu Natty 64 for that very reason.

Removing the plugin made vim start normally (probably by not loading the incompatible library in the first place).

You may disable your plugins and reenable them one by one to see whether Python is the culprit, or test  directly:

```
gvim -u NONE +'python3 print "test"'
```

On my box:

```
Fatal Python error: take_gil: NULL tstate
Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
Vim: Finished.
```

Conversely,

```
gvim -u NONE +'python2 print "test"'
```

Works correctly

Comment: Thank you @sehe!  Removing UtiliSnips just fixed my "gvim crashing without a trace" issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try verbose logging,

```
vim -V10/tmp/vim.log
```

You can also try running strace to see where it is bombing,

```
strace vim
```

It's possible that it's a permissions issue, but that's a guess.

Comment: This logging can be helpful in other cases but due to buffering you won’t receive the most meaningful part: on what command vim crashed. I do not know when buffering happens (it may be OS feature or vim one), but I do know that last lines are not written to disk when vim crashes.

Comment: At least this did not help me when I tried to determine why `frawor` crashes old vim without having a debugger like gdb on board. Trick with `vim -D` described in my comment to the question did help though.

Answer (score 2):

This surely took me a long time to debug, I indeed went through the painful process of manually disabling every plugin that I had installed and yet the same error kept popping up.

**[Solution]** : It  turned out that the gvim is tightly bound to the graphics settings used. We use a citrix client to remote login into UNIX servers and develop from there. As per my colleague's suggestion - I changed the color settings to "True Color 24 bit" and voila!!, things worked perfectly.

One of the classic examples of the times when we get hit by totally unsuspecting source of bugs!

Anyways, thanks for all your suggestions - I learned a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

try starting Vim like so:

`$ vim -u NONE`

which will disable all plugins to see if the problem still persists.

If it starts OK, move all the plugins from Vim's runtime directory (usually):

`~/.vim/`

on Linux & add them back one by one until the seg fault occurs.

Can be a tedious process especially as there may be a conflict between two or more plugins & in that case, it hard to ascertain when exactly they clash, but nine times out of ten, it usually gets you to the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, I will work them out and report on the results for future use.